# How can I download multiple URLs contained in a .txt file

Tags: url, gis, rstudio, wget

I have a .txt file which contains multiple URLs for downloading .tiff files.  These files are satellite derived sea surface temperatures that I'm using for a project.  Is there anyway to download all of the URLs from this .txt file without having to go through one by one and downloading images individually.  Here is a link to where all of the URLs were obtained from: [link](https://coastwatch.glerl.noaa.gov/erddap/tabledap/glerl_p_i_md1.htmlTable?url&fileType=%22.tif%22&time%3E=2016-04-01&time%3C=2016-09-14T14%3A11%3A00Z).  I'm not very skilled in computer science, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this RStudio? Do you have some R skills?

Answer (score 0):

`cat file.txt | while read file; do wget $file; done`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
wget -i list_of_urls.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like site sucker app?
It downloads websites and info.
https://geo.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZContentLink.woa/wa/link?path=mac%252fsitesucker&at=10lrCd&ct=stackoverflow